# Error messages in JSF and Richfaces

Tags: jsf, validation, richfaces

How can I display validation error messages in JSF and Richfaces in the form of an icon beside the field and a tooltip with the error message appears when the mouse hover on the error icon ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

- Use `<h:message tooltip="true" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" for=... />`: this way the detail will appear as tooltip, hide the summary, replace it with an icon ([see how](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/)).
- Create a `<rich:panel id="myid" rendered="#{bean.errorDisplayed}"><h:graphicImage src"patho/to/image.png" /></rich:panel>`, create the tooltip `<rich:toolTip for="myid"><h:message for="inputid" /></rich:toolTip>`, in the backingbean use [FacesContext.getMessages(String clientId)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessages%28java.lang.String%29) to check form messages. To get the clientId of the input use [UIComponentBase.getClientId](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/jsf/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29)
- Simply use `h:message`, and do some js tricks to wrap the displayed message in a tooltip, and display an icon (all of the js libraries have tooltip plugins).